# What is the meaning of 「真{ま｝っ無｛む｝」 in the sentence 「真っ無だったかな。」?

Tags: meaning, words, colloquial-language, sentence

The sentence is from [here](https://bilingualmanga.com/manga/kuro/chapter-1/5-2). The previous sentence is:

「そんなに目が見えないくらい。」

The translation given is "Where you always like this?".

I can't find 「真っ無」 in any dictionary, and a Google search for it only returns 4 results, none of which were helpful.

I assume this is some sort of colloquial grammar?

Comment: I’m Japanese, but I heard “真っ無” for the first time. I think this word is made by author of this book. In this case, “真っ無” mean “nothing at all”.

Comment: The other weird thing is that in Japanese orthography, っ cannot normally come before a syllable beginning with m- or n-. For example, 真 + 中 > 真ん中, not *真っ中.

Comment: I also think this could be someone entering 真っ黒 incorrectly, given the visual similarity between 黒 and 無.

Comment: Sometimes, an author will repurpose a kanji spelling for a different word.  I recall when I started reading Murakami Haruki novels, noticing that he'd use a kanji spelling for one thing, but give it furigana for a different word the first time.  Any chance that this sample sentence is preceded by some other instance of 真っ無 where the 無 has furigana indicating a different reading?  Otherwise, as @jogloran notes, the small-っ marker for gemination doesn't make any phonetic sense.

Comment: 「無」「黒」-- 確かに、点々４つあるし、似てると言えば似てるのかな・・・

Comment: I confirmed this is a mere typo. In [this sample available on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B00M8UIYF8/), this word has been already corrected to 真っ黒 ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNzvw.png)). Although 真っ無 makes some sense as a made-up word that means something like "true void" or "complete emptiness", it's not what the author meant to do. Voting to close this as a typo question.

Comment: @naruto これはｗ なまじありそうな文脈だけに余計たちが悪いミスですね…

Comment: Oh, the font is different from the original version on Amazon, too. So it looks like someone tried to add furigana and made a mistake.

Comment: @naruto The text in all manga on that website is purposely transcribed and over-imposed as actual HTML text on the image so it can be copy/pasted, scanned with addons like Yomichan, etc. It is to make it easier to look up words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear from the context that this is a typo for 真っ黒だったかな (with furigana applied by some kind of automatic process).

The interpretation of the first line would then be:

> クロを[飼]{か}っていて　[前]{まえ}とちょっと[違]{ちが}うなって[思]{おも}うことがあります

Since I started keeping Kuro, there's times that I think something's changed from before...

> そんなに[目]{め}が[見]{み}えないくらい[真]{ま}っ[黒]{くろ}だったかな

I wonder, was Kuro always so black that you almost couldn't see him at all?

As I observed in my comment, even if the intended reading was *mammu*, this can only be written as まんむ by the rules of Japanese orthography, and not まっむ. As such, I think it's more likely some automatic furigana process has failed to understand what to do with まっむ, and the intended intepretation is [真]{ま}っ[黒]{くろ} ("pitch black").

Comment: Any chance the text is meant to convey someone who doesn't speak Japanese very well?  違う

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi From the context of the rest of the manga, I don't get that impression. The girl isn't specified to be non-Japanese or anything along those lines. Since all the Japanese text on that website is transcribed by volunteers from the original mangas (so it can be over-imposed as HTML text for easy copy/pasting, Yomichan-ing, etc), the chances that this is a typo are high. And the user "naruto" confirmed from the original, that this is indeed a typo.

Comment: I finished reading the manga that's on the site. The version transcribed there has numerous other transcription/furigana errors so the typo seen by OP isn't surprising at all.

Comment: @jogloran That is good to know. I will keep an eye out while I continue reading.